# Jquery ui autocomplete bind new space event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I would like jquery auto complete to select the first item in the list and then on space select that item rather then on enter or on click. Should I append the code to the jquery ui java script file or is there a way to add another event for the space.

Thank you in advanced 
Matthew

Comment: How about keypress checking for space? In the documentation you can read about writing your own select functionality if I remember correctly.

Comment: Yes I am all readying doing that , I'll let you know the best solution I find.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change the code of the component ui.autocomplete (not recommended, it's better you create a new one),you have to change "keyCode.ENTER" to "keyCode.SPACE" in the following line:

```
case keyCode.ENTER:
                    // when menu is open and has focus
                    if ( this.menu.active ) {
                        // #6055 - Opera still allows the keypress to occur
                        // which causes forms to submit
                        suppressKeyPress = true;
                        event.preventDefault();
                        this.menu.select( event );
                    }
                    break;
```

if you want that both keys (enter and space) work, you only have to write:

```
case keyCode.SPACE:
case keyCode.ENTER:
```

To get the first element selected you only have to add "autofocus:true":

```
$( "#autocomplete" ).autocomplete({autoFocus: true,
  source: whatever
});
```

Here you can see it running:

http://jsfiddle.net/et86N/4/

Here you have the version where I create a new component called "ui.autocompletespace", that depends on jqueryui:

http://jsfiddle.net/52Csh/1/

More info about the component here:

http://api.jqueryui.com/autocomplete/